# Is there a hot-key to enable Storyboard panning with mouse in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: xcode, mouse, xcode-storyboard, pan

I'm looking for a hot-key, e.g. `spacebar` + `Click 'n drag`, that will enable me to use the mouse to pan Xcode Storyboard.

Obviously I can use the mouse-wheel to pan the storyboard, but it's far more tedious that clicking and dragging it to the exact location I want.

Is there a way to pan the Xcode storyboard with a click-and-drag motion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this unfortunately... Instead, there are a couple of tips on alternatives ways of moving things around in the Storyboard in this answer here: [Moving UI-elements in storyboard editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471484/1323652)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's unfortunate we can't easily pan the storyboard.

Comment: You can do this with a trackpad, so I know it's possible, however, I haven't figured this out on the mouse.

Comment: That's why I find XCode to be about 20 years behind the times. XCode is a pathetic editor.

Comment: Apple forgot to put the storyboard in a UIScrollView :D :D

Answer (score 33):

I know this is an old post, but I have been wondering the same thing recently and thought that I would post what I found for anyone else out there that is searching.

[Mac OS X Horizontal Scroll Trick](http://rohdesign.com/weblog/2006/9/21/mac-os-x-horizontal-scroll-trick.html). It's not exactly the same thing as panning, but it does let you scroll horizontally. Basically, hold down the shift key and use the scroll wheel to scroll horizontally. Let go to scroll vertically.

Comment: Been using Macs for years.  First time I heard this trick.  

Answer (score 19):

Not exactly the same as panning but it works for me

- Horizontal scroll | *Shift + Mouse Scroll*
- Vertical scroll | *Mouse Scroll*
- Zooming in and out | *Option + Scroll*

Comment: Any way to reverse the zoom direction? it seems opposite what one would expect.

Answer (score 3):

Found a good answer recommending [Smart Scroll](http://www.marcmoini.com/sx_en.html)

The grab and scroll(using middle mouse) is what you are looking for.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/85777

Answer (score 1):

I got one of those fancy mouse thingies without a scroll wheel but I can pan with it. Hold down shift and move your index finger over that mouse horizontally, vertically, etc... Works like a trackball.