# XCode: Moving UI-elements in storyboard editor

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

Is it possible to lock or freeze elements in storyboard editor so that they are ignored, when clicking and dragging?

My problem is that I have several elements underneath two big UIViews that cover the whole window. So in order to for example move a button underneath them I first have to move the big views out of the way, move the button, then move them back.

Is there a better way?

When I select the element in the tree-view on the left, it gets deselected as soon as I click on the storyboard. Perhaps there's a keyboard shortcut to keep the selection while dragging?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't I'm afraid, at least not that I've ever been aware of.

You can use the object navigator / tree-view on the left to select your items, then you can move objects around using the x/y/w/h properties on the size inspector.

Another solution could be to set the items you don't want to drag around to hidden while you're dragging other elements around.